# What is NSCache?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, macos

Can someone briefly explain to me when I would need to use NSCache? I read the documentation and I don't get it. Like, give me an example of a scenario where NSCache would be useful? 
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you ask? What would you like to use it for? What made you look into it? In short, what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Was browsing through list of classes in docs and came across it. Found it interesting...no particular reason.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's more or less just like a dictionary, with the following additional things (as mentioned by the docs):

> The NSCache class incorporates various auto-removal policies, which
>   ensure that it does not use too much
>   of the system’s memory. The system
>   automatically carries out these
>   policies if memory is needed by other
>   applications. When invoked, these
>   policies remove some items from the
>   cache, minimizing its memory
>   footprint.
>
> You can add, remove, and query items in the cache from different
>   threads without having to lock the
>   cache yourself.
>
> Retrieving something from an NSCache object returns an autoreleased
>   result.
>
> Unlike an NSMutableDictionary object, a cache does not copy the key
>   objects that are put into it.

You might use it if your application has lots of data that it needs to work with, but you can't keep it all in memory.  For example, if you had an app that pulled data from an SQL Lite database or a web service, you might store it in an NSCache after looking it up.  Then, when you need it again, you can check the cache first and only need to hit the database if it isn't in the cache.  The main advantage in this scenario over using a regular dictionary is that if you put too much stuff in the cache and it starts to fill up memory, it will automatically discard things to free up memory for you.

Comment: That is very interesting that it doesn't copy the key, i assume that means the key could change after it is set, which has a strange implication, of comparing key addresses or hashes. Presumably hashes still. I have to think about where I can use this. Other than using non NSCopying conforming keys.

Comment: The fun thing is that I've used to retrieve 27k entries from my local sql database and using NSCache now it takes less than a second instead of full 5 seconds. Thanks man

Comment: @Eugene Are the discarded objects retrievable? I don't know how to check for that myself because I don't know how to create a scenario where memory is needed and NSCache starts to discard objects.